# Shared preferences won't load after passing to another activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using Android-Studio and I have a few variables that I want to save locally using `SharedPreferences`

I put in some numbers and these are assigned to `float` variables and when I click a button a calculation is performed to assign float values to some other variables. I want these variables to then be saved locally and also passed to another activity to display on a screen.

So far I have this in my method when the button is clicked to add the data so that the variables are saved to `SharedPreferences`

```
//Save data with shared prefs


                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putFloat("totalPutts", totalPutts);
                editor.putFloat("totalGIR", totalGIR);
                editor.putFloat("nonGIR", nonGIR);
                editor.putFloat("totalHoles", totalHoles);
                editor.putFloat("GIRPutts", GIRPutts);
                editor.putFloat("nonGIRPutts", nonGIRPutts);
```

then I use an `Intent` to pass data to the next activity

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Stats.class);
                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                mBundle.putFloat("GIR", totalGIR);
                mBundle.putFloat("putts", totalPutts);
                mBundle.putFloat("nonGIR", nonGIR);
                mBundle.putFloat("totalHoles", totalHoles);
                mBundle.putFloat("GIRPutts", GIRPutts);
                mBundle.putFloat("nonGIRPutts", nonGIRPutts);
                intent.putExtras(mBundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

then get the data in the next activity

```
        showTotalGIR = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("GIR");
        showTotalPutts = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("putts");
        showTotalNonGIR = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("nonGIR");
        totalHoles = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("totalHoles");
        nonGIRPutts = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("nonGIRPutts");
        GIRPutts = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("GIRPutts");
```

Now when I click a button to return to the screen to add more data, I can put this in but when I click to go back to the activity to display the stats then it only shows the most recent data. So it seems that all the data is lost when I click the button to go back to the input screen.

I have tried adding a load button onto the data input screen and clicked this to load SharedPreferences data, but still not working.

```
//load shared pref

                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);

                totalPutts = sharedPref.getFloat("totalPutts", 0);
                totalGIR = sharedPref.getFloat("totalGIR", 0);
                nonGIR = sharedPref.getFloat("nonGIR", 0);
                totalHoles = sharedPref.getFloat("totalHoles", 0);
                GIRPutts = sharedPref.getFloat("GIRPutts", 0);
                nonGIRPutts = sharedPref.getFloat("nonGIRPutts", 0);
```

Am I doing something wrong somewhere? I have used SharedPreferences before and never had a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because, you are not writing it, you are just setting the value. You should use `apply()` after `.putFloat()` or whatever:

```
editor.putFloat("totalPutts", totalPutts).apply();
                editor.putFloat("totalGIR", totalGIR).apply();
                editor.putFloat("nonGIR", nonGIR).apply();
                editor.putFloat("totalHoles", totalHoles).apply();
                editor.putFloat("GIRPutts", GIRPutts).apply();
                editor.putFloat("nonGIRPutts", nonGIRPutts).apply();
```

Comment: Such a schoolboy error. Thanks for pointing out the obvious mistake

Answer (score 2):

After each writing(**put**) data to `SharedPreferences` you have to call `apply` so data would be actually saved. It's enough if apply is called only once after last put.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putFloat("totalPutts", totalPutts);
editor.putFloat("totalGIR", totalGIR);
editor.putFloat("nonGIR", nonGIR);
editor.putFloat("totalHoles", totalHoles);
editor.putFloat("GIRPutts", GIRPutts);
editor.putFloat("nonGIRPutts", nonGIRPutts);
editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers point out you need to `apply()` or `commit()` your changes for them to be available.

After @coroutineDispatcher whore his answer I decided to look up the implementation of `SharedPreferences.Editor#apply` ([Android Pie impl. found here)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java) to find out what goes on behind the scenes.

First thing to note is that each `apply()` will enqueue a new write operation so it is best to **do a single `apply()`** once you are done editing. The next question is related to the asynchronous nature of the write - **will it be persisted before your next activity starts?**

In practice it seems so, but I did not dig deep enough to see if it is actually guaranteed. Maybe someone else will answer this. To be sure you can use `commit()` which is blocking before navigating away or listen for the callback but this is probably overkill.